# problems with an icecast audio client

Tags: java, grails, audio-streaming, javasound, icecast

not sure if this is possible, I have an icecast server configured and streaming music, and I want to create a web player using Java (or grails). I managed to get the java web app playing the music icecast is streaming, using something like this:

```
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new URL("http://localhost:8000/musicstation"))
```

and after a few more lines the music is playing, the problem is that if I close the tab with the web app the music keeps playing, I have to stop the application to stop playing, but when I start it again and try to play again, it's like the icecast server continued playing the song in the background, I mean, it didn't stop or paused, because of this I cannot implement a pause action, since if I pause, what it actually be paused will be the web app playing the song, but in the background icecast will continue transmitting the song, so that when I play again after paused, the song won't continue from the point it was paused.

Is using AudioInputStream the correct way to implement an icecast audio client?
I hope I could explain myself.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Icecast obviously continues to "play", since it is a live streaming server. If you want to implement a pause mechanism, you need to buffer what you get from Icecast and play the buffer.

Comment: so if I want to create a player similar to spotify, do you think icecast would be a good option as a streamer server? What I want is to create a web player where the user could pause, forward, stop etc any song the user is playing, not sure if buffering what I get from icecast is a good approach, any suggestions?

Comment: or is it a correct approach developing an own Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP)?

Comment: Icecast is not the right thing to do this. A normal webserver would do.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit lost now, what do you mean with a normal web server? wouldn't I need a streaming server to accomplish that? Is a normal web server enough to host and stream a lot of different mp3/ogg files to different users/clients at different times?

Comment: what I would need to do is like a unicast on-demand server where any user could select any song and play it, not a live transmission. In a nutshell, like a new spotify or grooveshark. Now that I'm thinking maybe you are right, Icecast is not the right thing to do, but I think using a normal web server with http is not the correct way either, since as I been reading, streaming using http is completely inefficient, what would you suggest I should do?